# Complementability of von Neumann algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Is every von Neumann algebra complemented in its bidual? It is certainly true for commutative von Neumann algebras as their spectrum is hyperstonian. Is it 1-complemented?

Answer (score 8):

Every dual Banach space $X^{\ast}$ is complemented in its bidual $X^{\ast\ast\ast}$ with a projection of norm $1$: Indeed, the adjoint $(\iota_X)^{\ast}:X^{\ast\ast\ast} \to X^{\ast}$ of the canonical inclusion $\iota_{X}: X \to X^{\ast\ast}$ is left inverse to the canonical inclusion $\iota_{X^{\ast}}: X^{\ast} \to X^{\ast\ast\ast}$, thus $p = \iota_{X^{\ast}} (\iota_X)^{\ast}$ is a norm one projection onto $\iota_{X^{\ast}}(X^{\ast})$. Since by [Sakai's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#The_predual) a von Neumann algebra is precisely a $C^{\ast}$-algebra whose underlying Banach space is a dual space, a positive answer to both your questions follows immediately.

Comment: Maybe there are easier proofs, but I'm no operator theorist and my intuition says that it must essentially boil down to what I'm saying here. If I remember the usual proof of Sakai's theorem correctly, at some point it is even shown that the predual is complemented in its bidual, but I may be wrong here.

Comment: Just chanced on this while wasting time at office. It is certainly known that the predual of a vN algebra M is complemented in $M^*$ via an $L$-projection -- in the abelian case this theorem is older and has a name, which for now I forget. However, I don't know if this fact follows from the proof(s) of Sakai's theorem

Comment: @Yemon: I'm pretty sure that the abelian case was established (or at least nearly proved) by Grothendieck in *Sur une caracterization vectorielle-métrique des espaces $L^1$* where he proved the abelian version of Sakai's theorem. [See also my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55386/), where you'll find the bibliographic details and a link. Thanks for pointing it out, though.