# The space of all bounded sequences over a Banach Algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products, banach-algebras

If $A$ is a commutative Banach algebra, can we identify $l^\infty(A)$ as the dual of $ l_1\hat\otimes A$ (the projective tensor product of $l_1$ with $A$? Also, what do we know about the quotient space $l^\infty(A)/c_0(A)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**No**. Take $A=c_0$. Then $c_0$ is complemented in $\ell_\infty(c_0)$ (just project down on the very first coordinate). Note that $c_0$ is never complemented in a dual Banach space as this is equivalent to being complemented in $c_0^{**}\cong \ell_\infty$, which is apparently not the case.

See t.b.'s answer for [Complementability of von Neumann algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46679/complementability-of-von-neumann-algebras)

Regarding the quotient space $\ell_\infty(A)/c_0(A)$, it is mysterious enough even for $A=\mathbb{C}$. What would you like to know?